# Scraping table in RVest when there are multiple rows that span columns

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the following webpage: https://rptsvr1.tea.texas.gov/cgi/sas/broker?_service=marykay&_program=sfadhoc.budget_report_2022.sas&_service=appserv&_debug=0&who_box=&who_list=031901

Initially, I tried this code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
webpage = read_html("https://rptsvr1.tea.texas.gov/cgi/sas/broker?_service=marykay&_program=sfadhoc.budget_report_2022.sas&_service=appserv&_debug=0&who_box=&who_list=101912")
tables <- html_nodes(webpage, "table") %>%
  html_table()
budget = tables[[2]]
```

Then I realized that the results were messy, because html_table() cannot read tables where rows span multiple columns. I could clean the dataframe up after scraping it, but I'm wondering if perhaps there's a way to scrape it that avoids the issue in the first place.

I read the answers to similar questions, but they all involved a situation where only the header rows spanned multiple columns, or only the first column spanned multiple rows. In this case, this table is made up of multiple tables squished together, so it's like there are headers all throughout the table. Is there a solution that can deal with rows spanning columns throughout the table?

Comment: Is this just for fun? There is a download as Excel option. I assume you want to end up with a single dataframe similar to flat file format?

Comment: There are over 1,000 pages similar to this for every school district in Texas, so downloading each Excel file individually would be infeasible. I want to learn how to scrape one page and create a single dataframe so that I can then create a loop that goes through all the pages.

Comment: Please see my answer below then

Answer (score 0):

One way could be as follows:

1. Decide on your final format. I have selected a flat file format which entails splitting some header values, those with merged cells, into separate new columns, and repeating these values later
2. Gather and loop all the rows of data
3. In the loop process the row according to a set of rules
4. Generate your output row in the loop and write to a sized list
5. Drop empty entries list
6. Convert to DataFrame and add any additional info wanted

The rules I chose to apply where based on looking at the first column of each row as follows (pseudo-code):

```
if (first column className contains "linecontent") {
  if (if first column has br and span child elements) {
    split colmn text, after trimming, on line break
    assign split to red and measure columns (re-use as filldown)
  } else {
    assign measure the trimmed column text
  }
} else {
  we are on a non-header row so grab the $ and % values by matching on class "data"
}
```

---

R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr2)

page <- request("https://rptsvr1.tea.texas.gov/cgi/sas/broker?_service=marykay&_program=sfadhoc.budget_report_2022.sas&_service=appserv&_debug=0&who_box=&who_list=031901") %>%
  req_headers(
    "user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0",
    "accept" = "text/html",
    "connection" = "keep-alive"
  ) %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_html()

rows <- page %>% html_elements(".table tbody tr")

row_data <- vector("list", length(rows))
row <- 1

for (row_node in rows) {
  first_column_node <- row_node %>% html_element("td")
  first_column_node_classname <- html_attr(first_column_node, "class")
  is_new_column <- if_else(grepl("linecontent", first_column_node_classname), 1, 0)
  column_needs_split <- if_else((length(html_elements(first_column_node, "br")) > 0 &
    !is.na(html_element(first_column_node, "span"))), 1, 0)
  node_text <- first_column_node %>% html_text2()
  data <- NULL

  if (is_new_column) {
    if (column_needs_split) {
      new_values <- trimws(str_split_1(trimws(node_text), "\\n"))
      red <- new_values[[1]]
      measure <- new_values[[2]]
    } else {
      measure <- trimws(node_text)
    }
  } else {
    data <- row_node %>%
      html_elements(".data") %>%
      html_text2()
  }

  if (!is.null(data)) {
    row_data[[row]] <- c(c(red, measure), data)
    # print(c(c(red, measure), data))
    row <- row + 1
  }
}



row_data <- discard(row_data, is.null)
df <- do.call(rbind, row_data) %>% as.data.frame()

colnames(df) <- c(
  "red", "category", "measure",
  "gen_fund", "gen_fund_perc", "gen_fund_per_student",
  "all_fund", "all_fund_perc", "all_fund_per_student"
)

summary_info <- page %>% html_element('.c.systemtitle') %>% html_text(trim = T)

additional_info <- str_match_all(
  gsub("\\n", "", summary_info),
  "(\\d{4}\\s-\\s\\d{4}).*Totals for (.*?)\\sISD.*?\\((\\d{6})\\)"
)


df$year <- additional_info[[1]][, 2]
df$district <- additional_info[[1]][, 3]
df$isd_code <- additional_info[[1]][, 4]

head(df)
```

---

Sample output:

```
> head(df)
       red          category                                           measure     gen_fund gen_fund_perc
1 Revenues Operating Revenue Local Property Tax from M&O (excluding recapture)  $70,019,020        15.03%
2 Revenues Operating Revenue                             State Operating Funds $333,999,269        71.68%
3 Revenues Operating Revenue                                     Federal Funds  $59,326,937        12.73%
4 Revenues Operating Revenue                                       Other Local   $2,644,317         0.57%
5 Revenues Operating Revenue                           Total Operating Revenue $465,989,543       100.00%
6 Revenues     Other Revenue                       Local Property Tax from I&S           $0         0.00%
  gen_fund_per_student     all_fund all_fund_perc all_fund_per_student        year    district isd_code
1               $1,823  $70,019,020        15.03%               $1,823 2021 - 2022 BROWNSVILLE   031901
2               $8,695 $333,999,269        71.68%               $8,695 2021 - 2022 BROWNSVILLE   031901
3               $1,544  $59,326,937        12.73%               $1,544 2021 - 2022 BROWNSVILLE   031901
4                  $69   $2,644,317         0.57%                  $69 2021 - 2022 BROWNSVILLE   031901
5              $12,131 $465,989,543       100.00%              $12,131 2021 - 2022 BROWNSVILLE   031901
6                   $0   $9,212,992        17.23%                 $240 2021 - 2022 BROWNSVILLE   031901
```